Maximum bending of plate
I need to figure out what is the maximum bending of a plate that can be applied without deforming it. For example, with a flat steel plate of 1mm thickness, 10mm width and 100mm length, bent (along its length and against its thickness) by applying forces such that the plate takes the shape of a circular arc (for instance, the shape of 3/4 of a circle with about 20mm diameter):

What is the elasticity limit in term of minimum diameter that can be reached so that the plate recovers its flat shape when the force stops?
At this limit, what is the force (in kg/m2)?
How to find the properties of different types of materials (steel, iron, plastics. etc) necessary for the computation?


Could you clarify how is the plate supported and how are the loads applied? Shape of arc is achieved only when one end is fixed and the other is loaded by a bending moment.

I will try the following: insert thin plates (1mm x 10mm x 15mm) into a glove below my 3 semi-paralyzed fingers, going from the base of the wrist to the end of the fingers. This should help keep my fingers straight. They are not fully paralyzed; I can bend them but not tend them. If I clench my fist, parts of the fingers and palm will exercise a force on the plate that I can assume uniform or at 4 points. I would like to be able to clench my fist down to an inner diameter of about 20mm without reaching the elasticity/plasticity limit of the material.

When you bend a straight plate into a curved one with radius $r$, then the maximum stress will be:
$$\sigma_{max} = \frac{E}{1-\nu^2}\cdot \frac{z_{max}}{r}$$
where:

$E$ is Youngs modulus
$\nu$ is Poisson ratio
$z_{max}$ is maximum distance from neutral axis to surface, which in case of pure bending is half of the plate thickness

(If the section is more like a beam (similar width and height), there is $1$ instead of the $1-\nu^2$, but I think that is not your case.)
So if your section has a rectangular shape with height of 1 mm ($z_{max} =$ 0.5 mm) and width of 10 mm, just the height is important for maximum curvature in elastic state but the width of course affects rigidity. If this is from a common structural steel with:

$E = $ 200 000 MPa
$\nu =$ 0.3
$R_e =$ 235 MPa (yield stres)

You can use this with the first equation:
$$R_e = \sigma_{max} = \frac{E}{1-\nu^2}\cdot \frac{z_{max}}{r}$$
So the minimum radius for elastic bending is:
$$r = \frac{E}{1-\nu^2}\cdot \frac{z_{max}}{R_e} = 468 \text{ mm}$$
Such radius would be barely noticeable at the length of 15 mm.
You could almost halve the radius using titanium, which has comparable yield strength but lower Youngs modulus.
So if you aim for 10 mm radius you will definitely need to reduce the thickness $h$:
$$h_{max} = 2r\cdot R_e\cdot \frac{1-\nu^2}{E}$$
which for the structural steel is about 0.02 mm, which is 10 times thinner than a razor blade.
If you could have the insert on the outside instead of inside, you can increase the required radius and also the maximum thickness in elastic state. This option could be also safer.
Alternative solution for helping the fingers straighten could be to have guided tension springs on the outside of fingers. Or spiral springs on finger sides like here.

To get a circular deformation you need to apply equal moments to each end, because M/I=E/R(=s/y), that is the bending moment will need to be constant along the length.
Handily the third part of that equation tells you the stress, s, at a distance y from the neutral axis, in your case d/2
Myield=1/12  (b)( d^3)(d/2)(yield stress)

The easy way to subject your plate to a uniform moment that will bend it into a section of a circle is to apply equal and opposite moments, M, to its ends. This same moment will be uniformly carried across the plate.
Moment of Inertia (I):
$$I=\frac{BH^3}{12}$$
Elastic Section Modulus (S):
$$S=\frac{2I}{H}$$
Maximum Elastic Moment (M_elastic):
$$M\_elastic = F_y \cdot S $$
Substituting ( S ):
$$M\_elastic = F_y \cdot \frac{2I}{H} $$
Radius of Curvature (R):
$$R = \frac{E \cdot I}{M} $$
Substituting M, with M elastic
$$R = \frac{E \cdot I}{F_y \cdot \frac{2I}{H}} $$
$$R = \frac{E \cdot H}{2 \cdot F_y} $$
Assuming E, modulus of elasticity of steel= 30000ksi and F-y=50ksi:
$$R = \frac{30,000 \cdot H}{2 \cdot 50} \\ R=\frac{30,000 \cdot H}{ 100}$$
$$R=300H=300mm$$
So your plate can not bend into a radius of 20mm without permanent deformation.
The maximum elastic moment $M_{elastic)$:
$$S=\frac{BH^2}{6}=10*1^2/6=1.66,mm^3$$
We need to convert ksi to kg.mm2 by multiplying by 0.7030
$$M_{elastic}= F_y\cdot S=50ksi*0.703 \cdot 1.66=58.34,kg.mm$$

Thank you all. Looking for material with adequate Young's modulus and yield strength: ABS plastic (Acrylonitrile butadiene styrene) was a good choice. I did a prototype with two 0.5mm-sheets inserted in a glove on the top of the hand as suggested by Tomas: one for the first phalanx that needs more strength, one for all phalanges. The sheets were formed by heat with a curvature opposite to the closed fist. This kind of does the job: my fingers are almost extended, right level of strength to close the fist, and little permanent deformation of the plastic. I will try to improve it.


Comment
The topic is Strength of Materials for this question. More suitable for the Engg Stack Exchange.
If hinge supported at two points and loaded by two inner points the inner portion deforms to a pure circle ( Euler-Bernoulli Law) and outer part is a cubic third degree parabola by means of a triangular bending moment M variation.
Stress is found by relations such as $ \sigma = \frac{M}{Z}$ where Z is the section modulus which is dependent on section geometry, which should not go to plastic range by loading in order to recover its original shape when load removed..
EDIT1:
ok, then I think a constant force or a constant torque Neg'ator spring would be more suitable. From a sample of this material a tailor made ( with or without heating, cold rolling to thin out strips) a spiral spring of proper thickness sewn into gloves could be useful. Please google under this name to explore many possibilities; this type of material is suggested because because stiffness is low almost zero, original shape is easily regained by opening and closing the hand fist.
Negator spring
The above example is a random pick from net images, I have no other connection to it.
There are also shaped memory alloys (NiTinol) but not sure if can be procured to be used by water cooling/heating.

I didn't know about engg stack exchange. Indeed, this is about strength of materials. I took a lecture at university with a good grade, but 38 years ago... This is not for a homework but to think about a design of a prosthetic apparatus for one of my hands that became paralyzed a few years back overnight. I used the stress relation to compute the necessary thickness of the beam to avoid plasticity, assuming a force applied uniformly on each point of the plate. Now, I need to compute what would be the curvature resulting from this force. I will dig a bit more.
